# Android Listview item repeated

Tags: android, listview, repeat

When first load my listview it shows correct items, when i go back and load again it will show the entire items repeated again. Again, When I go back and load the same the entries repeated again.

For ex: on first time it has 4 items, on second time its 8, on third time its 12 and so on.

the below is my `customarrayadapter's` `getView()` method.

public class CustomArrayAdapterHistory extends ArrayAdapter {

```
ArrayList<RequestHistory> historyList = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;

public CustomArrayAdapterHistory(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<RequestHistory> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    historyList = objects;
    this.context=context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return super.getCount();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.request_history_items, null);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    ImageView imageView= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    TextView date= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);

    Log.e("Date","....."+historyList.get(position).getDate());
    date.setText(historyList.get(position).getDate());
    if(historyList.get(position).getserviceName()!="null")
        if(historyList.get(position).getserviceName()!="")
            textView1.setText(historyList.get(position).getserviceName());
    if(historyList.get(position).getreplyNote().equals("")){
        textView3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        textView3.setText("Reply: " + historyList.get(position).getreplyNote());
    }
    textView2.setText("Booking Details: " + historyList.get(position).getBookingdetails());


    if(historyList.get(position).getStatus().equals("0")){
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pending);
    }
    else if(historyList.get(position).getStatus().equals("1")){
       Log.e("STATUS ID","....."+historyList.get(position).getStatus());
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cross);
    }
    else if(historyList.get(position).getStatus().equals("2")){
       imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tick);
    }
    return v;
```

please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Delete the old list

Comment: show your logic for setting adapter to listview

Comment: post your constructor, I want to see how you initial your `historyList`. I think problem is that point

Comment: first of all, call `historyList.get(position)` once at first and assign it to a variable then use that variable. and second, include the whole adapter in your answer.

Comment: change `getCount`. it should return the size of the list. return `historyList.size()`

Comment: When you call constructor of Adapter at that time you are inserting items in array list without clearing that list.

Comment: I changed the return statement in getCount to return historyList.size(). But still its repeating

Comment: Solved the issue. I clear the arraylist everytime before setting it to adapter. Thank you all for the support and solution

Comment: Let try to delete the old list or convert arraylist to set. To convert see here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-list-to-set-arraylist-to-hastset/.

Comment: refer to launcher modes for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your getView method items should be like this

```
if( convertView == null ){
        //We must create a View:
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);
    }
    //Here we can do changes to the convertView, such as set a text on a TextView 
    //or an image on an ImageView.
    return convertView;
```

Comment: this is only for performance. it won't help with the issue. his problem is in `getCount()` method. and probably in `getItem()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Check third parameter `ArrayList<RequestHistory> objects` in your adapter constructor. It seams it expands every time you call constructor.

Answer (score 0):

after change of `getCount` to below, it's no problem with your adapter. in activity that uses the adapter, you must clear and reassign the list that you pass to your adapter constructor before call the it.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return historyList.size();
}
```